# How to checked checkbox if boolean value is true?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, checkbox, boolean

I'm working on jsp application and I have a form that has a checkbox, I retrieve data from my database which has a bit field named "principal", I can get the value of this field which is a boolean but I can't checked or unchecked the checkbox depending on the value of "principal".

Here's my JSP code:

```
<tr>
 <td>Principal:</td>
  <td colspan="2">
   <input type="checkbox" id="a_principal" name="a_principal" value="<%=directorio.isPrincipal()%>"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(function (){
    if('#a_principal' == true){
         $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
    }else{
        $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
    }
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `.prop` instead of `.attr()`

```
$(function (){
    if($('#a_principal').val()== "true"){           
         $("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dC4Zw/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `prop` to set checked property and get your if condition right. `attr` is not guaranteed to work against boolean properties of element and prop is. [See the difference here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName). Also the condition `'#a_principal' == true` is always true.

```
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $('#a_principal').length); 
// i dont know if you meant $('#a_principal').prop('checked') then
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $('#a_principal').prop('checked'));  
//but here :checkbx generic selector will select a_principal as well, so be specific
```

Providing your complete html will help solving your issue in a better way however try this:

```
   var $principal = $('#a_principal');
   $("input:checkbox").not($principal).prop('checked', $principal.prop('checked'));
```